# NVCC doesn't unroll small nested loop

Tags: cuda

I was wondering, why NVCC isn't able to unroll the following Cholesky factorization kernel for small matrices (N=4).

```
template<typename T, int N>
__device__ inline
void choleskyKernel2(T* C){
#pragma unroll
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
#pragma unroll
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            double s = 0;
#pragma unroll
            for (int k = 0; k < j; k++){
                s += C[i*N+k] * C[j*N+k];
            }
            s = C[i*N+j] - s;
            C[i*N+j] = (i == j) ?
                        sqrt(s) :
                        (1.0 / C[j*N+j] * (s));
        }
    }
}
```

The generated PTX code looks like this:

```
sqrt.rn.f64     %fd12, %fd29;
    st.local.f64    [%rd1], %fd12;
    rcp.rn.f64  %fd34, %fd12;
    mul.f64     %fd13, %fd30, %fd34;
    st.local.f64    [%rd1+32], %fd13;
    fma.rn.f64  %fd35, %fd13, %fd13, 0d0000000000000000;
    sub.f64     %fd36, %fd31, %fd35;
    sqrt.rn.f64     %fd14, %fd36;
    st.local.f64    [%rd1+40], %fd14;
    mul.f64     %fd15, %fd32, %fd34;
    st.local.f64    [%rd1+64], %fd15;
    ld.local.f64    %fd37, [%rd1+32];
    fma.rn.f64  %fd38, %fd15, %fd37, 0d0000000000000000;
    sub.f64     %fd39, %fd33, %fd38;
    rcp.rn.f64  %fd40, %fd14;
    mul.f64     %fd16, %fd39, %fd40;
    st.local.f64    [%rd1+72], %fd16;
    mov.f64     %fd58, 0d0000000000000000;
    mov.u32     %r58, -2;
    mov.u64     %rd40, -8;

BB1_5:
    shl.b64     %rd23, %rd40, 3;
    sub.s64     %rd24, %rd1, %rd23;
    ld.local.f64    %fd41, [%rd24];
    fma.rn.f64  %fd58, %fd41, %fd41, %fd58;
    add.s64     %rd40, %rd40, -1;
    add.s32     %r58, %r58, 1;
    setp.ne.s32 %p3, %r58, 0;
    @%p3 bra    BB1_5;

    sub.f64     %fd43, %fd6, %fd58;
    sqrt.rn.f64     %fd19, %fd43;
    st.local.f64    [%rd1+80], %fd19;
    mul.f64     %fd20, %fd8, %fd34;
    st.local.f64    [%rd1+96], %fd20;
    ld.local.f64    %fd45, [%rd1+32];
    fma.rn.f64  %fd46, %fd20, %fd45, 0d0000000000000000;
    sub.f64     %fd47, %fd9, %fd46;
    mul.f64     %fd21, %fd47, %fd40;
    st.local.f64    [%rd1+104], %fd21;
    mov.f64     %fd59, 0d0000000000000000;
    mov.u32     %r59, -2;
    mov.u64     %rd41, %rd1;

BB1_7:
    mov.u64     %rd5, %rd41;
    ld.local.f64    %fd49, [%rd5+64];
    ld.local.f64    %fd50, [%rd5+96];
    fma.rn.f64  %fd59, %fd50, %fd49, %fd59;
    add.s64     %rd6, %rd5, 8;
    add.s32     %r59, %r59, 1;
    setp.ne.s32 %p4, %r59, 0;
    mov.u64     %rd41, %rd6;
    @%p4 bra    BB1_7;

    sub.f64     %fd52, %fd10, %fd59;
    rcp.rn.f64  %fd53, %fd19;
    mul.f64     %fd24, %fd52, %fd53;
    st.local.f64    [%rd1+112], %fd24;
    mov.f64     %fd60, 0d0000000000000000;
    mov.u32     %r60, -3;
    mov.u64     %rd42, -12;

BB1_9:
    shl.b64     %rd26, %rd42, 3;
    sub.s64     %rd27, %rd1, %rd26;
    ld.local.f64    %fd54, [%rd27];
    fma.rn.f64  %fd60, %fd54, %fd54, %fd60;
    add.s64     %rd42, %rd42, -1;
    add.s32     %r60, %r60, 1;
    setp.ne.s32 %p5, %r60, 0;
    @%p5 bra    BB1_9;
```

Clearly the loops aren't unrolled and expensive local memory is used (My goal is to do everything in registers only).

I'm calling the function like so:

```
    T l[N*N];
    for(int i = 0; i < N*N; ++i){
        l[i] = buffer[offset+i];
    }

    choleskyKernel2<T,N>(l);

    for(int i = 0; i < N*N; ++i){
        buffer[offset+i] =  l[i];
    }
```

Is there a way to properly unroll this loops so everything can be done in registers?

EDIT:

Full code:

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

template<typename T, int N>
__device__ inline
void choleskyKernel2(T* C){
#pragma unroll
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
#pragma unroll
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            double s = 0;
#pragma unroll
            for (int k = 0; k < j; k++){
                s += C[i*N+k] * C[j*N+k];
            }
            s = C[i*N+j] - s;
            C[i*N+j] = (i == j) ?
                        sqrt(s) :
                        (1.0 / C[j*N+j] * (s));
        }
    }
}

template<typename T, int N>
__global__ static
void test3(T* buffer){
    const int matrixElements = N * N;

    T l[matrixElements];
    for(int i = 0; i < matrixElements; ++i){
        l[i] = buffer[i];
    }

    choleskyKernel2<T,N>(l);

    for(int i = 0; i < matrixElements; ++i){
        buffer[i] =  l[i];
    }
}

int main(){
     thrust::device_vector<double> d_data(16);
     test3<double,4> <<< 1,1 >>>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_data.data()));
}
```

Comment: Only the maintainers of the CUDA compiler can answer this with certainty. However, some common compiler heuristics for unrolling are: (1) start by unrolling innermost loops (2) *fully* unroll loops with "small" trip count known at compile time (3) *partially* unroll loops with "large" trip count. Your innermost loop has "small" but variable trip count, therefore fails conditions (2) and (3).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I can't tell you *why* nvcc (or indeed cicc which performs the device code compilation on behalf of nvcc) doesn't unroll your loops, I can show you how to change the code so that it does.

Turn

```
#pragma unroll
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
#pragma unroll
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
```

into

```
#pragma unroll
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
#pragma unroll
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            if (j <= i) {
```

and you will find all loops unrolled with no use of any local memory.

This is even though you didn't ask for the load and store loops to be unrolled. In fact, with my change above you don't need any `#pragma unroll` directives at all.

Comment: Why not `for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) { if (j > i) break; `?

Comment: The aim is to create a control flow that matches one of the compiler's unrolling heuristics. Historically the CUDA compilers have not been good at unrolling loops with a `break` statement, and in this case that still appears to be true.

Comment: Really? I mean, a loop with a fixed number of interations and no fidding with the loop counter in the body? Isn't that trivial to unroll? Or rather, are you sure nvcc is bad at unrolling those?

Comment: Trivial to a human maybe, hard for a machine that hasn't been programmed to do it. Try it out...